# Disable Action Bar button in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to disable a button in Action Bar in Android? I was looking around and I could not find any code snippet for that, I was thinking that there should be some easy way.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. Once you perform the user action when you want to disable the action bar, set some flag, say `disableButtonFlag`.
2. Call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. This will trigger `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be invoked to regenerate your menu.
3. Finally modify your `onCreateOptionsMenu` to disable the button you want depending on the state of `disableButtonFlag`.

   ```
   if (disableButtonFlag) {
       menu.findItem(R.id.your_item).setEnabled(false);
   } else {
       menu.findItem(R.id.your_item).setEnabled(true);
   }
   ```

   Or more simply:

   ```
   menu.findItem(R.id.your_item).setEnabled(!disableButtonFlag);
   ```

Comment: But I need ActionBar, I have requirements for the application. I need to continue using ActionBar and when the user adds one file I need to disable adding more files (button for adding files is in ActionBar).

Comment: Oh disable button, edited. I assumed remove the action bar, generally what disable the action bar seems to imply generically.

Comment: How could I do this from my Fragment/Activity super class? I have a side navigation menu which swaps out the content fragment in my activity. When the side menu is opened, I want to disable all of the actionbar buttons. Using the above method I would have to do this in every content fragment class. Is there a way to do it from a parent fragment class more generically?

Comment: You would now call `requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()` if you are in a fragment

Answer (score 6):

A simple method to disable a button in the action bar is to save a reference to the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);    
    mMenu = menu;    // Save reference
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and then call `setEnabled()` on the menu item to enable or disable:

```
mMenu.findItem(R.id.my_action_item).setEnabled(false);
```

No need to re-create the menu by calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Answer (score 3):

For Android developers who are using a custom `ActionBar` i.e (Save & Cancel action buttons), I have tried the following code to disable Cancel action button as follows:

**Java code:**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View actionBarButtons = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.edit_event_custom_actionbar, new LinearLayout(this),
                false);

        View cancelActionView = actionBarButtons
                .findViewById(R.id.action_cancel);
        cancelActionView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        cancelActionView.setEnabled(false);

        View doneActionView = actionBarButtons.findViewById(R.id.action_done);
        doneActionView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        this.getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarButtons);
```

**edit_event_custom_actionbar.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?attr/dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <!-- id must match corresponding menu item id -->
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
    style="@style/EditEventCustomActionButton"
    android:text="@string/cancel_label" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_cancel" android:padding="5dp" />

    <!-- id must match corresponding menu item id -->
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/action_done"
    style="@style/EditEventCustomActionButton"
    android:text="@string/abc_action_mode_done" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark" android:paddingRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And add this code to your /values/styles.xml:**

```
<style name="EditEventCustomActionButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.your_item).setEnabled(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: But it should be enabled at the beginning, I need to disable later, after user action. Please read the comment above. Thanks.

Comment: Just create a `Menu` attribute in your activity and initialize it in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: I found the way how to call invalidateOptionsMenu, but basically it was this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to disable the button when it's tapped, it's as easy as:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    item.isEnabled = false
}
```